# .Net Which is the most efficient method?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Which is the most efficient method to capture null fields from DB when populating a form?

Method 1 Try Catch

```
 Try
    txtKPIName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Name")
 Catch ex As Exception
    txtKPIName.Text = ""
 End Try
```

Method 2 isDBNull

```
 txtKPIName.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Name")), "", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Name"))
```

What do you guys think?

Comment: ofcourse the method 2 -- less is more

Comment: NEVER use exceptions to drive your code.

Comment: catching exceptions is computationally expensive, so don't do it unless you really have to.

Comment: and also the second one is wrong. Use If not IIF

Comment: Please use the NULL CHECK, try catch is not a method driving concept, it is a failure scenario.

Comment: To expand on Steve's point, `IIf` is an obsolete legacy function that has been superseded by the ternary `If` operator.  The operator is preferable because it is type-safe and will short-circuit (won't evaluate the false branch when the condition is true and vice versa) whereas the function returns `Object` and will evaluate both the true and false result regardless of the condition.

Comment: thank for the IIF info, im aware i use lots of legacy calls, its due to many years VB4/5/6 development.
I used to have to write my own inline If functions years ago in some instances.. so sort of stick with what i know, but will change that habit now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataRow(index).ToString()` will return empty string for `DbNull` value - so you can use one of these methods

```
txtKPIName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Field(Of String)("Name")
```

Or

```
txtKPIName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Name").ToString()
```

If you prefer to use condition with `if .. else` - then use `DataRow.IsNull` method and `If` method for one line `if` statement

```
Dim row =  ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)
txtKPIName.Text = If(row.IsNull("Name"), "default value", row.Field(Of String)("Name"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [null-Conditional Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators). They are pretty elegant to prevent cascades of ifs.

```
var stuff = ds?.Tables(0)?.Rows(0)?.("Name");
```

Comment: This is not what OP doing in his example. `?.` operator will return `null` when value is `null`, but OP needs to return empty string/some default value

Comment: It's a solution for preventing exceptions by checking for null without an `if()` within an `if()` within an `if()`. Returning string.Empty instead of `null` isn't exactly the interesting part of the question. As far as i know, one-line `If( expression, A, B)`is the VB version of the ternary operator.

Comment: "Null-Conditional operator" is an elegant solution, but using it in a way you do - will move possible exception far away from actual reason. Instead of having exception in line where data row is null - you will get exception in the line somewhere else where you will use `stuff` variable.